# Why does Int(false) work but Int(booleanVariable) does not?

Tags: swift, swift3

The code shown below:

```
Int(false) // = 1, it's okay

//but when I try this
let emptyString = true //or let emptyString : Bool = true
Int(emptyString) //error - Cannot invoke initializer with an argument list of type '(Bool)'
```

Can anyone explain this fact? It's confusing. What happens inside?

Comment: This is not allowed in swift 3.

Comment: I don't think that it's duplicated, the question is "why", not "how". The title of the question should be edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out what is going on with `Int(false)`, change it to:

```
Int.init(false)
```

and then <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `init`.  You will see that it is calling this initializer:

```
init(_ number: NSNumber)
```

Since `false` is a valid `NSNumber` and `NSNumber` conforms to the protocol `ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`, Swift finds this initializer.

So why doesn't this work?:

```
let emptyString = false
Int(emptyString)
```

Because now you are passing a `Bool` typed variable and `Int` doesn't have an initializer that takes a `Bool`.

In Swift 2 this would have worked because `Bool` was automatically bridged to `NSNumber`, but that has been removed.

You can force it like this:

```
import Foundation // or import UIKit or import Cocoa
Int(emtpyString as NSNumber)
```

This only works if Foundation is imported.  In Pure Swift there is no `NSNumber`, of course.

Comment: Perhaps add that this requires Foundation to be included, `Int(false)` won't compile in pure Swift environment.

Comment: @MartinR, about a 'Foundation' question - I can compile this in swift playground with 'import UIKit'

Comment: Yes, `import UIKit` also imports Foundation.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness: `NSNumber` conforms to `ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral`, that's why you can pass the `false` literal as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @MartinR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let intValue = emptyString ? 1 : 0
```

**Update**

You want to use Int(), use this

```
Int(NSNumber(value:emptyString))
```

Comment: yes, I know about this, thanks. But my interest is to understand the fact in my question :)

Comment: Cool. You cannot convert int to bool like that, if you need convert to NSNumber hope this helps

Comment: But why can I convert 'false' or 'true' by Int(false)?

Answer (score 0):

`Int` doesn't have initialiser with `Bool` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not have something like this somewhere in your codebase:

```
extension Int : ExpressibleByBooleanLiteral {
    public init(booleanLiteral: BooleanLiteralType) {
        self = booleanLiteral ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

Because otherwise, the line like `let foo = Int(false)` should not compile.